# Calculated Formula in Swedish Language

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, calculated-column-formula, language

I have the following calculated Column formula

```
=CONCATENATE(Title
             ,LEFT("00000"
                   ,5-(LEN(
                           TEXT(NextNumber,"0")
                          )
                      )
                  )
             ,TEXT(NextNumber,"0")
            )
```

which perfectly works is my English list but its not working in my Swedish list. Can someone translate it to Swedish.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://support.office.com/sv-se/article/Funktionen-HITTA-06213f91-b5be-4544-8b0b-2fd5a775436f?CorrelationId=a7ca6e58-2351-447c-a53d-bd4d6fdf50a1&ui=sv-SE&rs=sv-SE&ad=SE

Comment: Or maybe here, sorry, I don't speak swedish: https://support.office.com/sv-se/article/Introduktion-till-databer%C3%A4kningar-94e1b4cc-cd1c-49c2-80ec-90c9b9591f47?ui=sv-SE&rs=sv-SE&ad=SE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it help to change the separator from `,` to `;`?

Comment: It worked perfectly.